# How can I select second element and after that in CSS?

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I want to select element tags in html with CSS. For example, how can I select second li a Plus any thing after that in one UL. I want to set left-margin for second li plus any after that. First `<li><a>` do not move to right and fix, but other move to right with margin-left

```
        <ul style="list-style:none;">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Project</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">aboutUs</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

ContactUs                        Home                   Project                    aboutUs
   I want to keep margin-left of ContactUs and do not go to right   ,but set margin-left after second li with 50px for home + project + aboutUs;

Comment: Reverse your thinking (select the first one separately from the others, as opposed to selecting the others separately from the first) and use [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child).

Comment: I want to keep first li ,and do not move to right  but other li move to right with 50 px

Comment: Please See Again I Update my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/MFtU2/1/

```
ul > li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

If you wish to support legacy browsers that do not support the CSS3 `:not()` selector, your best bet is to select the first `li` and give it `margin:0;` while giving all `li` a margin of `50px`: http://jsfiddle.net/MFtU2/3/

```
ul.ie8safe > li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

ul.ie8safe > li {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Given that the OP has changed the parameters of the question slightly, I figured I'd update my answer. In addition to wanting to target all `li`s other than the first, you also want to get them to display on the same horizontal plane. To do this, you'll want each `li` to take up the minimum amount of space possible since, by default, each `li` will take up the full width of the containing `ul`. There are a couple ways to do this, but I prefer using `float: left;`

```
ul > li {
  float: left
}

ul > li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

I've attached an **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MFtU2/5/)** to show what this would look like. Note that this technique will work across legacy browsers as well as newer ones.

Comment: Note that [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) is not supported in IE8 or lower, if older browser compatibility is an issue.

Comment: **@ajp15243** An excellent point, definitely worth noting. The alternative would be to style all the `li` tags with `margin-left: 50px;` and then specifically target the first `li`. I have updated my answer to include this information.

Comment: @user3370683 You'll need to provide more details than that, otherwise we can't really help any further.

Comment: **@user3370683** set up a fiddle to show me what's not working. If you check out the fiddles that I posted, you can see that it is working given the information that you've provided.

Comment: I want to keep first li ,and do not move to right  but other li move to right with 50 px

Comment: this navigation should be in one line with none style

Comment: Please See Again I Update my question

Comment: @user3370683 Ahh well that was not part of your question now was it. Here is an **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MFtU2/5/)** with all the `li`s on one line. The key is to use `float: left;` to get them all on the same horizontal plane.

Comment: I Saw Your Code in Fiddle, It not my Purpose.

Comment: It is Work  and this is my purpose.

Comment: ul > li {
    float: left
}

ul > li:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

ul.ie8safe > li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

ul.ie8safe > li {
    margin-left: 50px;
}